# Inverse of $I+MW$

Tags: matrices, inverse

According [Constrained clustering via affinity propagation](http://faculty.ucmerced.edu/mcarreira-perpinan/papers/cvpr08a.pdf), the inverse of $I+MW$ can be computed in closed form using
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} & -A^{-1}B \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $M$ and $W$ are symmetric matrices and $A$ is apparently a $2L\times 2L$ matrix where $L$ is the number of non-zeros entries in the upper triangle of $M$ (discounting the diagonal).

Anyone can explain me how this works ?

Comment: It could be referring to the particular $M$ and $W$ in the paper ($K$ and $M$).

Answer (score 0):

You may try
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 0 & I
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
W & X \\ Y & Z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\ 0 & I
\end{pmatrix}$$Then expand left hand side and compare terms, find W, X, Y, Z.